# A $1/2$-Lipschitz function $f$ from $[0,1)$ to $[0,1)$ that has no fixed point?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I thought that $f(x) = 1/2x + 1/2$ might be a solution. However, I am also doubting it because of bijectiveness... is it necessary? Is it too obvious?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you doubt that example?

Comment: If there is a fixed point $x_0$, then just see what $f(x_0) = x_0$ gives you.

Comment: FWIW, a real-valued $1/2$-Lipschitz function $f$ of one variable "reduces diameter by a factor of at least $2$" almost by definition. (Precisely, for every set $A$, $\operatorname{diam} f(A) \leq \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{diam} A$.) No such function can map a bounded interval onto itself (unless we consider points to be intervals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example does the job. The function is injective but not surjective (onto).

Any continuous surjective function from $[0,1)$ to itself must have a fixed point. Either $f(0) = 0$, or $f(0) > 0$ and $f(c) = 0$ for some $c > 0$. In the latter case the function $g(x) = f(x) - x$ must have a zero in $(0,c)$ and thus $f$ must have a fixed point there.